# Django not serving eot files

Tags: django

I have following structure (inside static directory):

```
    css
    --stylesheet.css
    --fonts
    ---flexslider-icon.eot
```

stylesheet.css opens correctly in browser (like mysite.com/static/css/stylesheet.css)
But eot file is processed by django.
Why?
All js and css files, as well as images open correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with a different browser? Some browsers will work quirkily with font files.

If trying with other browsers doesn't do the trick,

Are you using the default web server? Have you tried running your site with Gunicorn web server (http://gunicorn.org/)? Its a very simple test to do.